# Python shutil.copyfile Limitation on name length

Tags: python, python-3.x, copy

In my case various tests run and their results to be stored in each of the test folder.
The test names can be a long string like TESTCase9012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890 and I have to create a file names like TESTCase9012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890.txt for which I am using shutil.copyfile as follows.

```
source = "C:/TEST_FOLD/Git1_FOLD/ver1_animationss_folder/ver1/TEST1_00/TC1/TC1_001/001/version2test/ver/run_test_vers/tes_1612191617TEST/summary/DOR/test_00_result/tesresult.txt"
destination = "C:/TEST_FOLD/Git1_FOLD/ver1_animationss_folder/ver1/TEST1_00/TC1/TC1_001/001/version2test/ver/run_test_vers/tes_1612191617TEST/summary/DOR/test_00_result/TESTCase9012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890/TESTCase90123456789012345678901234567890123457890.txt"

destiny = shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
```

But it returns error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    dest = shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
  File "C:\TEST_FOLD\Git1_FOLD\ver1_animationss_folder\ver1\WinPython\python-3.6.1.amd64\lib\shutil.py", line 121, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
C:/TEST_FOLD/Git1_FOLD/ver1_animationss_folder/ver1/TEST1_00/TC1/TC1_001/001/version2test/ver/run_test_vers/tes_1612191617TEST/summary/DOR/test_00_result/TESTCase9012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890/TESTCase90123456789012345678901234567890123457890.txt
```

Is there any limitation of name length for the copyfile function?
How to overcome this limitation?

Comment: first check if file and folders exist.

Comment: as I know limitation may have system Windows or file system used on disk and you can't change it.

Comment: source file and destination folder does exists

Comment: Thanks Furas.
It is Windows limitation of 256 char for the entire file path.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file

As I am using windows 10 I am able to remove the limitation as mentioned in the above link.

Answer (score 2):

The regular DOS paths is limited to 260 characters. You can exceed this limit by using an extended-length path that starts with the `\\?\` prefix. The path must use backslash as the path separator.

e.g.

```
source = '\\\\?\\C:\\TEST_FOLD\\Git1_FOLD\\ver1_animationss_folder\\ver1\\TEST1_00\\TC1\\TC1_001\\001\\version2test\\ver\\run_test_vers\\tes_1612191617TEST\\summary\\DOR\\test_00_result\\tesresult.txt'
```

Note that each slash is replaced with a double backslash